# How to pass IERC20 as argument in solidity?

Tags: solidity, blockchain, tokens, uniswap, smart-contract-wallets

i'm trying to deploy sushiSwap on my local machine. but i don't know what should i pass a argument in constructor...
code is like...

```
pragma solidity 0.6.12;

import "./IERC20.sol";
import "./ERC20.sol";
import "./SafeMath.sol";


contract SushiBar is ERC20("SushiBar", "xSUSHI"){
    using SafeMath for uint256;
    IERC20 public sushi;

    constructor(IERC20 _sushi) public {
        sushi = _sushi;
    }

    // Enter the bar. Pay some SUSHIs. Earn some shares.
    function enter(uint256 _amount) public {
        uint256 totalSushi = sushi.balanceOf(address(this));
        uint256 totalShares = totalSupply();
        if (totalShares == 0 || totalSushi == 0) {
            _mint(msg.sender, _amount);
        } else {
            uint256 what = _amount.mul(totalShares).div(totalSushi);
            _mint(msg.sender, what);
        }
        sushi.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), _amount);
    }..
```

. so on

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you need to pass a contract instance (or an interface which describes an instance) you pass an `address`. So you just need to pass in the address of a contract which implements `IERC20` .

In your case I'm not sure if there are some extra requirements for what `_sushi` should exactly be - any `IERC20` will be syntaxically correct but it probably has some other requirements as well (is it the LP token perhaps?).